# Form positioning when using TStyleManager in Delphi XE7 application

Tags: delphi, position, themes

I'm trying to make a Delphi application form remember it's position and recall it the next time the application is started:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadSettings;
var
  xml : IXMLDocument;
  node : IXMLNode;
begin
  [ ... initializing XML ...]

  // Loading theme
  if node.HasAttribute('Theme') then TStyleManager.SetStyle(node.Attributes['Theme']);

  // Loading position & size
  if node.HasAttribute('PosTop') then self.Top := StrToInt(node.Attributes['PosTop']);
  if node.HasAttribute('PosLeft') then self.Left := StrToInt(node.Attributes['PosLeft']);
  if node.HasAttribute('PosWidth') then self.Width := StrToInt(node.Attributes['PosWidth']);
  if node.HasAttribute('PosHeight') then self.Height := StrToInt(node.Attributes['PosHeight']);

  [ ... some other stuff ... ]
end;
```

Everything works fine when the "Theme" is set to default "Windows" theme. With any theme, the form appears at it's default position set up by Windows, close to the upper left display corner, no matter where the form was located before.

Any ideas about what may be the cause and how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't tell when you call this function. Can't we have a [mcve]? We don't need any xml. That's irrelevant. Hard code the coords.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to properly restore form's position you have to set it initial `Position` property to `poDesigned` in form designer.

Default `Position` property is `poDefaultPosOnly`. That means your form position will be determined automatically by Windows. Depending at which point you trigger your own form positioning during the form creating process and depending on other code you may either successfully change forms position or not.

However, if the `Position` property is `poDesigned` all positioning will be left to Delphi code itself and you will be able to properly apply your setting.

**Why?**

Because if you use any code that will trigger form's window recreation, that code will again try to set your form's position to Windows default one and can interfere with your positioning process.

Calling `TStyleManager.SetStyle` does exactly that.

---

Simple test case for above would be creating new VCL project, adding some style to it and put following code in `FormCreate` event

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Styled: boolean;
begin
  Styled := true;

  if Styled then TStyleManager.SetStyle('Silver');

  Top := 200;
  Left := 300;
  Width := 800;
  Height := 600;
end;
```

If `Styled` is `false` setting position works, if it is `true` it doesn't.

Comment: I knew it must be something that simple. Works like charm, many thanks!!!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then please accept it. [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)